# Update Image source from AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use to update Label values inside the AJAX success function like below, But I need to know how I'm going to apply this method to change/update "src" of an `<img id="myimage" src=""/>`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'clmcontrol_livematchupdate',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (data) {

        $('#mstatus').html(data.matchstatus);
        // $('#myimage').... ?

    },
    complete: function () {
        // Schedule the next request when the current one has been completed
        setTimeout(ajaxInterval, 4000);
    }
});
```

Comment: `$("#elementId").attr("src","value");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using jquery, You can use like `$("#myimage").attr('src','img url');`

Assume, you have response like `data.imgsrc` then it should be like, `$("#myimage").attr(src, data.imgsrc);`

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'clmcontrol_livematchupdate',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (data) {

            $('#mstatus').html(data.matchstatus);
            $("#myimage").attr('src','img url');

        },
        complete: function () {
            // Schedule the next request when the current one has been completed
            setTimeout(ajaxInterval, 4000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I agree with $("#myimage").attr(src, data.imgsrc); but the src part should come inside quotes like 'src' right? cause it didn't work until I do so.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#myimage').attr('src', '/imagePath/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#mstatus').html(data.matchstatus);
    $('#myimage').prop('src', 'VAlue'); //change image src
}
```

---

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)